# Problems with parsing a JSON Array after retrieving from firebase when using ionic-selectable

Tags: arrays, json, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm currently developing an App using Ionic 3 and Firebase. I'm using ionic-selectable (you can see my [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-selectable-form-control-7dkjrq)) for the user to select an option from my firebase database array and return the selected option to the user's id.

I have got everything to work, except that ionic-selectable is not reading the retrieved array form firebase.

I'm retrieving the array using the following code:

```
    this.itemsRefdiag = afg.list('medicalhx');
    this.items = this.itemsRefdiag.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({ ...c.payload.val() }));
    });
    const dgRef = this.afg.database.ref();
    dgRef.child('medicalhx').orderByChild('name').on('value', snapshot => { this.snapshot2 = JSON.stringify(snapshot).replace(/"[0-9]":{"name":|{|}/g, ""); })
```

My console.log results in:

```
"Hyperthyroidism","Hypothyroidism","Diabetes Type 1","Diabetes Type 2"
```

However, when using ionic-selectable for `private diagnoses: Diagnosis[] = [this.snapshot2]`, I get 'undefined' options. However, when I manually type in `private diagnoses: Diagnosis[] = ["Hyperthyroidism","Hypothyroidism","Diabetes Type 1","Diabetes Type 2"]`, it works. I also tried parsing the JSON array using the following code instead:

```
this.itemsRefdiag = afg.list('medicalhx');
    this.items = this.itemsRefdiag.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
        return changes.map(c => ({ ...c.payload.val() }));
    });
const dbRef = this.afg.database.ref();
dbRef.child('medicalhx').orderByChild('name').on('value', snapshot =>
{     let snapshot3 = JSON.stringify(snapshot).replace(/"}/g, `"`);
let snapshot4 = snapshot3.replace(/"[0-9]":{"name":|{|}|"/g, "");
this.snapshot2 = snapshot4.split(",");
  });
```

My console.log results in an Object with separate strings (an array):

```
["Hyperthyroidism","Hypothyroidism","Diabetes Type 1","Diabetes Type 2"]
```

However, ionic-selectable still doesn't seem to read that and I get undefined error. Any ideas on what I may be doing wrong with the array?

**EDIT**

It actually does work the second time around, however the console error pops up the first time and I believe this is because it's not waiting for the array results to pop-up the first time around. Is there a way to add a wait time until the array loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second code listed in the question converting it to a real array worked but required a loading time, hence poping up a console error. I managed to get around the loading time issue by implementing Asynchronous searching as per this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-selectable-form-control-bh9gqg).